# Newsletter Sign up

Tags: control-panel, emails

I am trying to create a Newsletter registration form. I just want to collect emails somewhere in the CP, and let the client decide what to do with the list later on.

Has anyone worked on something similar? I don't want to create a registration, just data collection.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

- You could use the [Guest Entries](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries) plugin. You'd create a section ala "Newsletter Subscribers", and add a couple fields like Name (`subscriberName`) and E-mail (`subscriberEmail`). Then could take the form example and add your name and e-mail field to it:
- ```
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input id="name" name="fields[subscriberName]">

  <label for="email">E-mail</label>
  <input id="email" name="fields[subscriberEmail]">
  ```
- I'd really reccommend you to use a system like MailChimp or Campaign Monitor for this instead. André Elvan built a great plugin to handle the former, [MailChimp Subscribe](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/mailchimp-subscribe). It's kind of a non-brainer, unless your client already is invested in another system.

Comment: I had looked into the Guest Plugin, but that created different entries for each email signup. I am looking for something that creates a list. I also talked to the client about MailChimp and Constant Contact, but he just wants a list. Thanks anyway

Comment: If i'm understanding you correctly, I think you can solve that easily by making a template that list all your entries. You can output it as CSV, JSON, a html table or whatever you like. If it's a problem for you that it's creating new entries, you can also add a signup as a new row to a Matrix field in a predefined entry.